# objective-c changing images by a click of a button

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have recently started coding in objective C. I am creating a tictactoe game in objective-c using x-code. I am trying to change one image to another when a button is clicked. I have tried the following code but with no luck. Below is my code for that button.

```
(IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender { image.image = [UIButton imageNamed:@"x.jpg"];
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Luck has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

add your image in **Assets** and initialize UIImage with image name.

```
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "UIImage" should be before imageNamed, not "UIButton"
2. You need a minus sign '-' before (IBAction)
3. You need a closing brace at the end of your function

If you've gotten your code to compile, and it's still not working at runtime, please give us more details of the exact behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to toggle button image always do

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"#IMAGE NAME#"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code below should work, it's set up so that the button itself will cause the UIImage you have to change to a new image. Initially you want to declare a property of NSString which will hold the string relative to your image. This should be placed at the top of the .m file after the `@interface` and should look like `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringNameExample;`.

From there, in the `viewDidLoad` you want to assign that property a value, of the image name. For example `self.stringNameExample = @"image.jpg";`.

`-(IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender {
  self.UIimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: imageNameExample];`
}

If you want the button to change the image back to normal I would suggest an if function to check for the current string for the UIImage.image value - use my example to have an option to alternate between two images based on its current state.